# Unable to boot from cloned SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, clone

I've "cloned" a drive to SSD and now I can't boot from the SSD. If I pop the original HDD back in the laptop, it boots fine. The laptop has only one SATA port, so to clone the drive, I installed the master and recipient drives in my desktop. I'm using Easus Partition Manger.

Results from research:

- there were no failures during the cloning
- when transplanted back into the laptop, the boot order is set correctly in the BIOS
- this is not quite the same problem as [Elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/1093305/windows-10-fails-to-boot-after-hdd-clone-to-ssd) [Or Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1391584/windows-10-not-booting-from-ssd-cloned-from-hdd), where those users seem to have multiple drive bays in the systems they're cloning
- I note a "Migrate OS" button", but that will only allow me to migrate the OS from which I'm presently booted. This is no good, since I don't want to boot my desktop from the donor laptop drive.
- I've tried booting from the Windows 10 install DVD and it is unable to automatically fix the problem
- I've tried fixing the MBR and it told me it worked, but it still don't boot.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: How did you clone?

Comment: The whole drive. Using the clone function.

Comment: Which cloning product? What exact function and parameters?

Comment: Per original post, Easus Partition Master and "Clone". Nothing other than default settings. Entire drive selected.

Comment: Basically, it looks like Easus "Clone" is a misnomer. It has neglected to clone the fact that the disk is bootable. I solved this by using Macrium Reflect. Its clone option does exactly what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I speculate that there are many definitions of "clone" and Easus' definition simply does not align with mine.

This was solved by instead using Macrium Reflect's "Clone" function. It worked perfectly.

(Disclaimer: Other disk copy products do exist and may serve equally well.)

Comment: 'Macrium Reflect's "Clone" function' +1. This is what I always do (4 times so far). Always works. Sometimes I just select a recent Macrium Reflect backup image I have made and restore it to the new drive.

Comment: It seems that EaseUS reserves bootable cloning for [EaseUS Disk Copy](https://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/home-edition/), which is a commercial product. Shame on them.

Comment: I reckon so. That should be more evident from their "documentation". I've not cloned a disk in maybe 20 years, and things have certainly changed. Back in the day, we spoke of a "sector copy" which was bit-for-bit.